# General Form of Integral $\int_{k}^{k_2} x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2}dx?$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there a general **algebraic** form to the integral $$\int_{k_1}^{k_2} x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2}dx?$$ I know that if this integral is an improper one, then the integral can be calculated quite easily (i.e. is a well known result). However, when these bounds are not imposed, I am getting results in the form of the error function which turns out to be another integral. So I am confused if this can even be solved by hand or the only way to do so is to plug it in through a calculator.

The reason I am asking is because this integral is highly related to physics as in that it is the proportional to the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution. So if I want to know the number of particles between two velocities, I have to calculate this. I am sorry if this is a basic question. I just could not find anything similar online.

I would also be interested in the results if only the upper bound is $\infty$ and the lower bound is $k$.

Comment: Note that if we have a result for your last paragraph's query, then we would also have a result for your original query (by subtracting). Anyway, I think the usual way to write such a result is with the error function

Comment: I'm physicist too, and I've never seen any closed form for it. I'm sure there's no closed form at all.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}-\int_{k_1}^{k_2}\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha x^2}dx$$ which is where the error function comes from.

Comment: [Using WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%5E2%29%28exp%28-%28x%5E2%29%29%29+dx), $I = \int x^2 e^{-x^2}dx$ is given in terms of the error function $\text{erf}\,(x)$ in such a way that one can easily obtain $\text{erf}\,(x) = \frac{4I + 2xe^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}.$ Therefore, most any kind of "explicit form" that exists for $I$ would also have to exist for $\text{erf}\,(x).$

Comment: For the query, upper bound is ∞ and the lower bound is k, the following can be bounded, by taking $\alpha x^2 =t$ 
$$\frac{e^{-k}}{2\alpha^{3/2}} \le I \le \frac{e^{-k}(k+1)}{2\alpha^{3/2}}$$
$I$ is integrand.
Hope this might help.

Comment: You can integrate by parts to express $\int x^2 e^{-ax^2} dx$ in terms of $\int  e^{-ax^2} dx$.  This is why you get an answer in terms of the error function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the exact result
$$\int_{0}^{t} x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2}\,dx= \frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{4 \alpha ^{3/2}}\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\alpha } t\right)-\frac{t
   }{2 \alpha }e^{-\alpha t^2}$$

There are good or even very good approximations of $\text{erf}(y)$. I built some of them precisely for problems in physics.

The general idea is to write

$$\text{erf}(y) \sim \sqrt{1-\exp\Bigg[-\frac {4y^2} {\pi} P_{n}(y) \Bigg]}$$
where $P_n$ is the $[2n,2n]$ Padé approximant built around $y=0$. For example the simplest are
$$P_0(y)=1$$
$$P_1(y)=\frac {1+\frac{\left(10-\pi ^2\right) }{5 (\pi -3) \pi }y^2 } {1+\frac{\left(120-60 \pi +7 \pi ^2\right) }{15 (\pi -3) \pi }y^2 }$$

To give you an idea : using $P_0(y)$ (maximum error $=0.00629$)
$$\int_{0}^{+ \infty} \Big[\text{erf}(y)-\text{approximation}\Big]^2 \,dy=3.23 \times 10^{-5}$$ and  using $P_1(y)$ (maximum error $=0.00019$)
$$\int_{0}^{+ \infty} \Big[\text{erf}(y)-\text{approximation}\Big]^2 \,dy=3.04 \times 10^{-8}$$

For
$$\int_{t}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4 \alpha ^{3/2}}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{4 \alpha ^{3/2}}\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\alpha } t\right)+\frac{t
   }{2 \alpha }e^{-\alpha t^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{k_1}^{k_2}x^2e^{-(\sqrt{\alpha }x)^2}\,dx$$
let $u=\sqrt{\alpha}x\Rightarrow dx=du/\sqrt{\alpha}$

$$\begin{align}
I
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\int_{\sqrt{\alpha}k_1}^{\sqrt{\alpha}k_2}\left(\frac u{\sqrt{\alpha}}\right)^2e^{-u^2}du\\
=&\alpha^{-3/2}\int_{\sqrt{\alpha}k_1}^{\sqrt{\alpha}k_2}u^2e^{-u^2}du
\end{align}$$
then let $v=u^2\Rightarrow du=dv/2u$:
$$I=\frac{\alpha^{-3/2}}{2}\int\limits_{\alpha^{1/4}k_1^{1/2}}^{\alpha^{1/4}k_2^{1/2}}v^{1/2}e^{-v}\,dv$$

---

Then I would note the definition of the *Lower Incomplete Gamma function* which is:
$$\gamma(s,x)=\int_0^xt^{s-1}e^{-t}\,dt$$
Alternatively, using IBP on the equation in terms of $u$ you will get an expression in terms of the error function